# Enable Developer Dashboard on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is the Developer Dashboard available on SharePoint Online (Office 365)? How do you enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Nik this is not possible [link to source](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/office-365-and-sharepoint-online-guide-and-resources-for-sharepoint-on-premise-architects/):

> Developer Dashboard is not available in SharePoint Online for
>   customers. SharePoint Online doesn’t have great story regarding Error
>   logging and Monitoring. You can write custom framework which would log
>   errors in the SharePoint list but you can’t have much control over ULS
>   Correlation ID. If you are getting errors in OOB configuration, only
>   way to resolve issues is working with Microsoft Office 365 Support
>   team and supplying Correlation ID to the support team.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it is not available in SharePoint Online. I would expect the primary reason is that it is a farm level setting. This means that if you were able to turn it on, every customer that shares your environment would also see the update.